# ¿cómo conecto un proyecto c# a una base de datos mysql de hostinger?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de escritorio con `c#` y quiero conectarlo a una base de datos que tengo en *hostinger.es*.

Ya he importado la librería de conexión con mysql y puedo conectarme a una base de datos local, pero quisiera trabajar con una base en *hostinger*.

Estoy trabajando con este metodo:

```
public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
{
    MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=URL; database=DBName; Uid=UidName; pwd=PWD;");

    conectar.Open();
    return conectar;
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema exactamente? (De paso, no creo que sea buena idea que publiques tu nombre de usuario y contraseña aquí...)

Answer (score 1):

Para conectarte remotamente a bases de datos en Hostinger tu cuenta tiene que ser Premium o Business

https://www.hostinger.co.uk/knowledge-base/5

Comment: Por favor no cambies el contenido de la edición que hizo @Miquel. Se deben remover esos datos porque son privados, no públicos.

Comment: Yo también edite para ocultar sus datos privados, si chafe otra edición lo siento.

Answer (score 0):

Intuyo que como dices "aplicación de escritorio" y MySql en "hostinger" quieres conectarte a través de Internet. Si es así, abrirás un agujero de seguridad enorme.

Las causas por las que no te has podido conectar pueden ser varias. Entre ellas:

1. El MySQL solo está atendiendo peticiones originadas en localhost.
2. El cortafuegos del servidor tiene bloqueado el puerto del MySQL (por defecto es el 3306).
3. Tu router o cortafuegos en el escritorio tiene bloqueado el puerto 3306.

Mi recomendación es que configures una VPN entre el servidor y tu desktop.

Comment: @kevin Puscan Ortiz, lograste  solucionar  el problema?  yo  tengo  el mismo problema, espero  puedas  ayudarme